# How to view folder listing on Google Drive under "Shared with me"?

Tags: google-drive, google-drive-shared-folder

### In brief

Under `Shared with me` in Google Drive, there is **no folder listing**. So how can we browse the folder stree of the shared folder(s)?

### Full details

Currently when opening `Shared with me` page, here is what I see

[image]

So there is NO folder tree/listing for us to browse. How to browse the folders and sub folders of a given shared folder from my colleagues?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my workaround for this

- Open a file
- Go to menu `Move to folder`

[image]

- Hit the icon as @2 in the popup to view the folder listing

[image]

- Enjoy the familiar file listing and folder breadcrumb there

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should see the folder in the list if a folder was shared with you.

[image]

If individual files were shared, you can use [Nam G VU's method](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/153552/316120) to explore the folder path of only files shared with you.